# How to get the form data by postman in short way using golang?

Tags: go, struct

I am retrieving form data using postman, but the code is too long. Is there is any method for getting the data in short form? Here's the code I am using:

`Customer` struct:

```
type Customer struct {
 FirstName        string `json:"first_name" bson:"first_name"`
 LastName         string `json:"last_name" bson:"last_name"`
 Email            string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
}  
type Customers []Customer

type new_user struct {
 first_name     string 
 last_name      string 
 email          string
}
```

Function for retrieving the form data called by the route:

```
function GetData(c *gin.Context){
 first_name := c.PostForm("first_name")
 last_name := c.PostForm("last_name")
 email := c.PostForm("email")
 reqBody := new(new_user)
 err := c.Bind(reqBody)
 if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
 }
 customer.FirstName = first_name
 customer.LastName = last_name
 customer.Email = email
}
```

I'm getting 3 form values. Suppose I need to get 50 values, then the function will be much bigger.

Comment: Allways show full code. What is c.Bind?

Comment: @volker i edit it for you

Comment: If everything else is correct, (tags, field names, form keys, etc.) `c.Bind(customer)` should be enough. No need for `new_user` and calls to `c.PostForm`. *Just make sure `customer` is a pointer type*.

Comment: ... and here's an example: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/742#issuecomment-264681292 (note the `form` tags, they may be required for Bind to work, i'm not sure, give it a try and see)

Comment: @mkopriva yeah what you said it will works but the length of code is too long. There is no method for taking the form-data of the postman in short way? Means if i want to retrieve the 50 values then i write this code `c.PostForm` 50 times?

Comment: @mkopriva okay i will try this example

Comment: @gourav no, I said you don't need to use `c.PostForm` and in the example provided you can see they don't use it. Something like this should be enough https://play.golang.org/p/MqAdb7ygodR

Comment: @mkopriva okay i will understand what you want to say thanks for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the mkopriva tells me a short way to do this. I got the answer for it. It can be shorter by doing the following code.

```
type Customer struct {
 FirstName string `form:"first_name" json:"first_name" bson:"first_name"`
 LastName  string `form:"last_name" json:"last_name" bson:"last_name"`
 Email     string `form:"email" json:"email" bson:"email"`
}
```

In the function the code is:-

```
customer := new(Customer)
if err := c.Bind(customer); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
fmt.Println(customer)
```

It will print the data from the form-data of the postman.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse HTTP request body yourself, like to following

option 1:

```
import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin/json"
    "log"
)
type Customer struct {
    FirstName        string `json:"first_name" bson:"first_name"`
    LastName         string `json:"last_name" bson:"last_name"`
    Email            string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
}

func process(context *gin.Context) {
    var customer = &Customer{}
    req := context.Request
    err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(customer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal()
    }
}
```

option 2:

Encoding to map to decode to struct (not recommended)

```
import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "encoding/json"
    "bytes"
    "log"
)


type Customer struct {
    FirstName        string `json:"first_name" bson:"first_name"`
    LastName         string `json:"last_name" bson:"last_name"`
    Email            string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
}

func Process(context  *gin.Context) {

    req := context.Request
    var aMap = map[string]interface{}{}
    for key, values := range req.PostForm {
        aMap[key]=values[0]
    }

    var buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := json.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(aMap)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var customer = &Customer{}
    json.NewDecoder(buf).Decode(customer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for giving your time for me. I also appriciate your answer. But there is also a simple and easy way to solve this see i post my answer

Comment: I'm not so experience with  gin, is it really so much faster than mux server ?

Comment: also does it recognize post with various content types, multipart/form vs json/text